# Getting image_color from camera1394

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I'm trying to get the image from my Fire-i400 1394 camera. In order to do that, I am using the following comands:

$ rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node

$ ROS_NAMESPACE=camera rosrun image_proc image_proc

$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/image_rect_color

and this should give me the images, with color. But I'm getting the following message:

Color topic '/camera/image_color' requested, but raw image data from topic '/camera/image_raw' is grayscale

then, the images come up, but they are on grayscale.

Does anybody know why it is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60934/getting-image_color-from-camera1394/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-17**:
What parameters did you set for the camera driver?

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2013-04-18**:
Actually, I really don't know. I just plugged the camera, downloaded the packages, and, then, I calibrated it. How can I see these parameters? Thanks for your quick answer!

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-18**:
See [default params on that node's wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/#camera1394_node) if you didn't set any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a look at the [driver tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Tutorials).

They explain how to run the driver, configure color parameters, and access the parameters using dynamic_reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thank you joq! Actually, I just had to use $ rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node _guid:=(my_cam_guid) _video_mode:=640x480_rgb8